# No tap sound on button click - android

Tags: java, android, button, android-xml

I am not getting the sound which is generally heard when a user taps on any ui element `Button` in Android.

heres my button xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/continue_btn"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:background="@drawable/continue_btn_bg"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="-1"
    android:shadowDy="-1"
    android:shadowRadius="2"
    android:text="CONTINUE"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

the sound just doesn't come when I press this button. Touch Sounds are enabled in android settings.

Comment: from what you've shown there is no reason why u should be hearing a sound on touch

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought is was a default feature of android to play sounds on ui element tap action.

Comment: if your not performing any action by clicking of button its natural the sound wont come.@Are you performing any onClick event by pressing the button.

Comment: oh! yes, clicking the button takes you to the next activity.

Answer (score 4):

use    `button.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);`

Comment: Is there a way to implement this for all buttons at once. or i'll have to do this for all the buttons individually.

Comment: You have to do this for all buttons individually. This is one line only. Just add it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that the system will play the sound automatically once you have attached any action. For example "onClick" in xml.